# Facebook Post Privacy Not Working as Expected

Tags: facebook, post, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

I'm not sure what I'm missing here, but despite my best efforts I can't figure out why the following query string parameters (urldecoded) is somehow losing the post privacy settings.

```
message=We hope you enjoy your xxxx from xxxxxx
picture=http://app.xxxxx.me/_img/_product/thumb/1019.jpg
link=http://app.xxxxxx.me/object/xxxxx/1019/
name=Sample Post Name
description=This is a sample description message
properties={"Privacy":"Only You and xxxx can see this"}
actions={"name":"Track This Order","link":"http:\/\/apps.facebook.com\/xxxxxxx\/orders?id=3ff0f70e39c454acb800342b550b550f"}
privacy={"description":"XXXXX only","value":"CUSTOM","friends":"SOME_FRIENDS","allow":1111111111}  (where 1111... is a valid user numeric ID)
```

My goal is to post to the **target user's wall** (this is supposedly allowed, as specified in the Open Graph POST documentation, privacy, "note") with specific privacy settings.

More specifically, only the user and one other friend should be able to view the post.

I've tried virtually every JSON encoding variation for privacy, yet for some reason although the rest of the post parameters work perfectly, privacy does not.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: What permissions did you request from the user?  Also you can play around with the graph API using the API Explorer tool.  I find it useful to do things there until I know how to do it, then I implement and test it in the code.

Comment: many, but relative to this query, yes read_stream and stream_publish are authorized.  As for the graph explorer, no matter what ID I put in to test (my username, FB ID #, 'me') it always returns **(#100) Can only call this method on valid test users for your app.**  Obviously I'm authenticated on the app since I'm logged into the developer app, and it seems to function fine in the browser, so I'm not quite sure what's going on there

Comment: Try it out via the graph API Explorer tool.  Does posting to the authenticated user's own feed work as expected with those permissions?

Comment: Yeah, everything about the post works perfectly (even embedded objects like actions and properties) except for the privacy permissions.  When the post shows up, it is always set to a default of "Everyone"

Comment: Opps, I read your question as you are trying to post to a friend's wall, not to the user's wall.  Sorry for my misunderstanding.  Do you get the same results using the Graph API Explorer?  if so, then it's a Facebook bug (code or documentation).  If not, then it's an API bug.

Comment: Slightly different results.  When the POST request is issued from my app, it works sans privacy settings.  When the POST request is issued from the Graph Explorer, for me it always returns ** (#100) Can only call this method on valid test users for your app**  I've tried my access token, as well as requesting one from within the app.  All the parameters appear fine, so I'm not sure why I can't get past that error.  Also strange, occasionally it will give me a "Unsupported Post request" error.  Also to clarify, my access tokens are persistent & enabled for offline access

Comment: Also, to expand, what I am trying to accomplish is essentially the same as what a notification or private message used to be in the old REST API.  Since they don't really provide a lot of options for this that accomodate a rich interface, my plan is to post on the user's wall and set the privacy settings to only allow the recipient to see it.  If there's a better way of notifying users (Apprequests are great but don't work due to some of our required specifications) then this would become a non-issue

Comment: Good luck with your endeavor,  I'm outta ideas at the moment.  Hopefully someone will have an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Bug report filed on Facebook

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/221305621283801